# What order are CiviMail emails sent from CiviCRM?

Tags: civimail, email

Is there a clear pattern to the order in which emails are sent from CiviMail queues? For example, *emails are sent from the queue*

- *in no specific order*
- *sorted alphabetically, A-Z*
- *sorted by contact ID ascending*
- *...*

Wondering after seeing [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24688/civimail-is-only-sending-to-half-the-recipients).

Answer (score 1):

I understood it was smallest civi id first (or "sorted by Contact ID ascending" to use your description)

Comment: That's how I understood it as well - they'd go out in the order in which they were created (and therefore smallest ID to biggest).